# Undefined index: when reading array values - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This is the `var_dump` of my array `(var_dump $syn3):`

```
array(1) { 
     ["@attributes"]=> 
     array(2) { 
         ["date"]=> string(10) "Sun 16 Oct" 
         ["time"]=> string(5) "21:45" 

     } 
}
```

I am trying to pull out date and time:

```
foreach($array2 as $syn3) {     
    $datemovie = $syn3['@attributes']['date'];
    $timemovie = $syn3['@attributes']['time'];

}
```

The above results in

> PHP Notice: Undefined index: @attributes in

I don't get it - this should have worked. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I think the issue with `@` as a key.

Comment: I dont think `@` is the problem. https://eval.in/661838.  What is the actual array (`$array2`)?

Comment: show us `$array2`

Comment: But I'm not working with $array2. I want to work with $syn3

Comment: try with foreach inside foreach.: https://3v4l.org/JsZdh

Comment: $array2 reads: http://pastebin.com/P1tKKNsu

Comment: Mmm, debugging put a print_r of $syn3 in the loop. See what you get.

Comment: Array ( [@attributes] => Array ( [date] => Sun 16 Oct [time] => 21:45 ) )

Comment: Clear your problem, Checkout @SougataBose Example.

Comment: [mcve], please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$array = array("@attributes"=>array("date"=>'Sun 16 Oct', "time"=>'21:45'));
var_dump($array);
$datemovie = $array['@attributes']['date'];
$timemovie = $array['@attributes']['time'];
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> foreach($array2 as $syn3)
> ```

`$syn3` here has been changed to the first element of `$array2`

Use another name.

Comment: Surely, renaming wouldn't work. Do you mean renaming inside the for each loop?